# certificate SSH login does not work on 22 but other port

Tags: ssh, certificate

On my Red Hat server, the sshd will not accept my correct certificate login. However, If i start another sshd on another port, it works! (I assume the second sshd loads the same configruation files.)

second sshd started with:
`sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -p 54321 -d` #-d is optional and prints debug output

ssh `strange-host -p 22 -vvv` prints:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 528 bytes for a total of 2389
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
```

ssh `strange-host -p 54321 -vvv` prints:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 528 bytes for a total of 2389
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp 0f:1c:df:27:f7:86:49:a8:47:7e:7f:f3:32:1c:7d:04:a3:73:a5:72
```

So the question is why the difference?

I have thought of no way to get any helpful logging from the "standard" sshd to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Clearly, both instances have a totally different configuration. Did you restart the 'main' SSHD after reconfiguring? Why don't you configure your single instance to run on two ports? (mutiple `Port` definitions) What is the process behind port 22? (`netstat -ntlp | grep \:22`) Is this instance started with other options? (`ps aux | grep 1234`, replace pid from netstat output)

Comment: thanks for the input, the "main" is restarted. main cmdline is simply /usr/sbin/sshd (cat /proc/1234/cmdline). Starting main on another port wouldn't be good. I actually port-forwarded through "main" to even get to the secondary sshd as the firewall from my other host dont allow connecting through anything but 22.

Comment: this might be a hint, but the output should be normal: Dec 12 10:43:17 srvualo01 sshd[10821]: pam_krb5[10821]: error reading keytab 'FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab'

Answer (score 1):

What do you get if you enable dubug output and compare the results e.g.

```
ssh -vvv          user@host 'echo Done'  2>&1 > ssh_port22.log
ssh -vvv -p 54321 user@host 'echo Done'  2>&1 > ssh_port54321.log
diff ssh_port22.log ssh_port54321.log
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the relevant output to the question as you suggested.